# Use a for-loop of characters to plot several lines with specific colors

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, char

I would like to plot 13 lines on a single graph. Each line represents a subset of my data, grouped by the characters in column 'basin'. What I have works, but I'd like to make it more efficient using a for-loop.
[Here's what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTapP.png).

A simplified dataframe to work with:

```
env <- data.frame(basin = c('BLK','DUC','WHP','BLK','DUC','WHP','BLK','DUC','WHP'),
                  sal = c(5,6,3,2,4,5,6,8,4),
                  date = c(2013,2013,2013,2015,2015,2015,2017,2017,2017))
```

And a simplified version of what didn't work (it runs, but makes all the lines blue and solid):

```
basinlist <- c('BLK','DUC','WHP')
plot(sal~date, data = env, type = 'n', ylim = c(0,10), ylab = 'Salinity')
for(i in basinlist){
  lines(sal[basin==i] ~ date[basin==i], data = env, 
        col = c(4,4,2),
        lty = c(1,1,2))
}
```

[image]

The issue is that I don't know how to change the colors with each iteration when `i` is a character. Searching for this issue yields solutions for when `i` is a number, or for creating lines that are all different colors, neither of which are my goal.

This is the first time I've asked my own question rather than finding the answer posted elsewhere on SO, so let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: you need two variables: one for the `basin` and one for the color index: `for (ii in seq_along(basinlist)) {i <- basinlist[ii]; lines(sal[basin==i] ~ date[basin==i], data = env, col = c(4,4,2)[ii], lty = c(1,1,2)[ii])}`

Comment: That was the ticket! `seq_along` is what I needed. Just to be sure I understand, it makes a sequence of length `basinlist` (1:13), meaning I can use ii as numbers and i as the basin names?

Comment: you got it. most people tend to use `1:length(x)` instead of `seq(x)` or more safely for loops `seq_along(x)`, but if `x <- character(0)`, you get very different results from `1:length(x)` and `seq_along(x)`

Comment: @rawr can you post as an answer so I can mark as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case for each iteration in your loop, you need both the index of the vector and the variable itself. An easy way to get the plot you want is to iterate over the indices (`ii` in the example below) and also get the vector element with each iteration (`i` as you had before).

```
env <- data.frame(basin = c('BLK','DUC','WHP','BLK','DUC','WHP','BLK','DUC','WHP'),
                  sal = c(5,6,3,2,4,5,6,8,4),
                  date = c(2013,2013,2013,2015,2015,2015,2017,2017,2017))

basinlist <- c('BLK','DUC','WHP')
plot(sal~date, data = env, type = 'n', ylim = c(0,10), ylab = 'Salinity')

for (ii in seq_along(basinlist)) {
  i <- basinlist[ii]
  lines(sal[basin==i] ~ date[basin==i], data = env,
        col = c(4,4,2)[ii],
        lty = c(1,1,2)[ii])
}
```

[image]