# Repeat loop 100 times adding regression lines to same plot for each iteration

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a `while` loop that requires a sampling process be repeated until values of the sample column `value` are less than columns `rep1:rep4`. I would like to repeat this loop a set number of times, let's say 100.

For each successful loop, I would like to add regression lines to two separate plots. In this example, the `value` column would be providing data for the x axis, and data for the y axis would be coming from `y1` and `y2`. I've included the additional y column because there might be a number of variables that I would like to plot that would all be sharing the same x axis data. For this example, the end result would be two plots, one for `y1` and one for `y2`, each containing 100 overlapping regression lines.

I haven't included the sampling process code here because it is a bit overly involved and would probably distract from the main question here.

The basic `while` loop and sample data are provided below.

This thread [Use a for-loop of characters to plot several lines with specific colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622266/use-a-for-loop-of-characters-to-plot-several-lines-with-specific-colors) indicates that an additional `for` loop with `seq_along` might be the answer here. Different colors aren't an issue for me however, so that example might be more complicated than what is needed here.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  while (any(df$value[i]<=as.numeric(df[i,2:5])%>%na.omit())){

#sampling procedure here

}
}
```

Here is an example of the `df` layout:

```
    ID    rep1   rep2   rep3   rep4  y1  y2  value
1   a     NA     NA     NA     NA    5   2   -400
2   b     -400   NA     NA     NA    7   5   -300
3   c     -400   -300   NA     NA    3   3   -200
4   d     -400   -300   -200   NA    4   6   -300
5   e     -400   -300   -200   -300  9   7   -400
6   f     NA     NA     NA     NA    2   3   -400
7   g     -400   NA     NA     NA    3   2   -400
8   h     NA     NA     NA     NA    6   4   -400
9   i     NA     NA     NA     NA    7   4   -200
10  j     -200   -300   NA     NA    7   6   -300
11  k     -300   NA     NA     NA    8   9   -200
12  l     NA     NA     NA     NA    3   7   -300
13  m     NA     NA     NA     NA    4   7   -300
```

```
structure(list(ID = structure(1:13, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m"), class = "factor"), 
    rep1 = c(NA, -400L, -400L, -400L, -400L, NA, -400L, NA, NA, 
    -200L, -300L, NA, NA), rep2 = c(NA, NA, -300L, -300L, -300L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -300L, NA, NA, NA), rep3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    -200L, -200L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), rep4 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, -300L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), y1 = c(5L, 
    7L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L), y2 = c(2L, 
    5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 7L), value = c(-400L, 
    -300L, -200L, -300L, -400L, -400L, -400L, -400L, -200L, -300L, 
    -200L, -300L, -300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

I'd imagine this should work for the basic plots

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = value, y = y1)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = value, y = y2)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fit a regression line with `lm()` each iteration (since that is what `geom_smooth(method = lm)` does), summarise the necessary coefficients in a data.frame afterwards, and then plot all the lines at once?

Comment: @teunbrand I don't think a simple linear regression will be used, but rather something like a loess. Would the `lm()` function work for that? Along those lines though, since the y values aren't changing, rather than recording intercept data, maybe it would be easier to just record the `value` data in a `data.frame` and then plot as needed afterwards? If that's the case, how should the exterior `for` loop be set up to record the individual runs in a separate `data.frame`? If the runs were increased to a thousand, would the technique become more cumbersome than just plotting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your sampling procedure works as intended, and that the goal is merely to track the data frames from the `while` loop and plot this using `geom_smooth` (please clarify if I am misunderstanding). You could just save the variables of interest to a data frame, include an ID to track each data frame, and then group by these IDs when plotting. Below I am using the data you provided.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(4)

#an empty data frame to save our output
toplot <- data.frame(ID = NA, value = NA, y1 = NA, y2 = NA)

#loop for 50 times for this example
for(i in 1:50){

  #sampling the df. This would be your while loop. 
  #Just save your output from the while loop as an data frame object
  d1 <- sample_n(df, 5)

  #save the values of interest
  toplot_TMP <- data.frame(value = d1$value, y1 = d1$y1, y2 = d1$y2)

  #create ID variable
  toplot_TMP$ID <- i

  #bind to our data frame for later
  toplot <- bind_rows(toplot,toplot_TMP)

 }

#drop NA artifact
toplot <- na.omit(toplot)

#plotting with group = ID
ggplot(data = toplot, aes(x = value, y = y1, group = ID)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Gussy up as you need to.

Comment: That gets me past the wall I kept hitting. Thank you. The toplot data frame is going to be a beast, but it gets all of  the data I need recorded, organized, and ready to be visualized.